# AngularJS how to change the view after all the data in the destination controller is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following structure:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>...</head>

    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <nav class="side-nav">
            ...
        </nav>
        <header>
            ...
        </header>
        <main ng-class="navOpen">
            <div class="loading-screen" ng-if="!contentLoaded">Loading...</div>
            <div class="content" ng-view></div>
        </main> 
    </body>
</html>
```

MainCtrl handles all "application specific" stuff - navigation (like change the class of a link when route changes), loading screen, hamburger menu being clicked.

Now I want to add transitions between the routes. My idea is that the previous view stays until the `contentLoaded` variable is set to true. The `contentLoaded` variable gets set inside each controller; generally after an http request completes. That way I will be able to "blur" the previous content by adding opacity to the `loading-screen`'s background. After content is loaded, the previous view will be switched with the new view and the loading screen will disappear.

Is there a way to tell AngularJS to keep the view until a specific criteria in the controller is met? I am using ngRoute for the routing.

Comment: see "Animations" section in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: Thank you for the help! I ended up rewriting my core application code and used `resolve` property of ngRoute to load the content before switching the controllers; and the result ended up being so much cleaner and independent of child controller.